# Absolute value defined in a field

Tags: metric-spaces, field-theory

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be any field. Let $\left|\cdot\right|:\mathbb{K}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function which satisfies

- $\left|x\right|>0$ if $x\neq 0_{\mathbb{K}}$; $\left|0\right|=0$
- $\left|xy\right|=\left|x\right|\left|y\right|, \forall x,y\in\mathbb{K}$
- $\left|x+y\right|\leq\left|x\right|+\left|y\right|, \forall  x,y\in\mathbb{K}$

Now set $d(x,y):=\left|x-y\right|$. Is ($\mathbb{K},d)$ a metric space?. I can prove that $d$ is definite-positive and the triangular inequality, but I can't prove $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$

Comment: What do the first two bullets tell you about $|1|$ and $|-1|$?

Comment: ok, I found just now an answer by myself: $\left|-1\right|=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We see that $\lvert 1\rvert=\lvert 1\cdot1\rvert=\lvert 1\rvert\lvert 1\rvert$ and so $\lvert 1\rvert=0\mbox{ or }1$. Obviously $\lvert 1\rvert\neq 0$ and so $\lvert 1\rvert=1$. Also, $1=\lvert 1\rvert=\lvert -1\cdot -1\rvert=\lvert -1\rvert\lvert -1\rvert$ and so similarly $\lvert -1\rvert=1$. From this, we get
$$d(x,y)=\lvert x-y\rvert =\lvert(-1)(y-x)\rvert=\lvert -1\rvert\lvert y-x\rvert=1\lvert y-x\rvert=d(y,x).$$